# hyper-v accidentally removed snapshot

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, snapshot

I (very stupidly) moved a Hyper-V snapshot via Windows explorer and then, of course the VM server would not boot. I moved it back and then removed the snapshot via Hyper-V so there are no snapshots listed.

When I looked in explorer the snapshot was still taking up space so I moved it to another folder thinking that Hyper-V no longer needs it as it's not listed.

Hyper-V then complained that it was missing when trying to boot the server even though it's not listed.

I need to be able to remove this snapshot as we have ran out of disk space but am now unable to do so.

It's all a bit of a mess and I don't know what my next steps are.

Can anyone help?

Many thanks,

John

Comment: Have you tried using the Powershell cmdlets to see if you can manipulate the snapshot(s) like that ?

Comment: Entity_Razer - I am a novice so don't know anything about the Powershell. Do you have a link to any useful info?

Comment: You should not touch snapshot file directly. If you wish to remove it, you have to first merge it and then you should remove it from Hyper-V otherwise you will loss the data as well as your VPS may not boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

http://windowsitpro.com/hyper-v/delete-undeletable-checkpoint-hyper-v

Another usefull link might be this one:

https://gilgrossblog.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/cant-remove-hyper-v-backup-checkpointsnapshot-from-vm/

Hope this helps, regards

Comment: How do I get into a Powershell so that I can run those commands?

Comment: Start Powershell from the start menu. Should be installed on the servers if it's a 2008R2 or 2012.

If not, can be installed through featues